# A Strange Question of Identity

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

> It doesn't matter what you had for lunch.
>   Fat and weak, what a disgrace
>   Don't be vain and don't be whiny.
>   I'm too much man for you to take.
>
> You're the biggest joke on the Internet.
>   Nurse, I spy gypsies - run!
>   You will never find true happiness
>   Do I even need a I reason?
>
> I thought that I would go right out of my mind
>   Well, believe me, this has been one lousy day.
>   Oh man, I hate it when I'm right.
>   It's hard to keep the fans at bay.

Who am I?

Comment: Why am I reading this like a rap song ?

Comment: @Lordofdark `cc by-sa 3.0` GO GO GO!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are

> **Weird Al.**
>
>  Every line is from one of his songs, in order:
>
>  *Rye or the Kaiser
>
>  Eat it
>
>  Amish paradise
>
>  Fat
>
>
>
>  All about the Pentiums
>
>  Bob
>
>  Your horoscope for today
>
>  I'll sue ya
>
>
>
>  Hardware store
>
>  Jurassic park
>
>  Albuquerque
>
>  Genius in France*

Comment: Man, I had a hunch from the second line but couldn't figure out the rest, nice job!

Comment: My hunch came from the fifth.

Comment: I got the reference from line 1, and I knew all the songs, but I was hoping there was some deeper message hidden in there than just "who wrote all these lines?"  Guess I was overthinking it.